# HttpUrlConnection#setReadTimeout has no effect when POSTing large messages

Tags: java, httpclient

I have a problem where an external HTTP server that I need to POST large messages to is having OutOfMemory issues. My HTTP client code is not timing out.
It is possible to reproduce this behaviour by using kill -STOP  to pause the HTTP server process (to undo, use kill -CONT ).

I have found using the code below that if I keep my request small that the entire message is written to the output stream and the getResponseCode times out.

With a large message like the one below, the code ties up in the write to the output stream. I presume that I have filled the socket buffer. The code then never times out.

What I am looking for is a way of controlling the timeout when writing the request.

I have tried something similar using Apache HttpClient and got a similar result.
I tried running the Java code below in a different thread and interrupting it myself but the thread stays running.

I need to keep the streaming behaviour but I would appreciate any ideas into how I might be able to get the client code to time out.

Thanks,

PJ

```
        URL url = new URL("http://unresponsive/path");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(4 * 1000000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "4000000");
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            if(i % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("write: " + i);
            }
            os.write("test".getBytes("us-ascii"));
        }
        os.close();
        System.out.println("response-code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you are opening a cnnection and writing to the output stream.... I think the confusion is the role of reading vs writing.... Youre not reading from an input stream, when your code is hanging ... so the timeout won't have any effect to rescue the tie up ..

If there is a way to timeout the writing, your code can be fixed that way.

Comment: Thanks jayunit100. I understand that the read timeout should apply only to the reading of the response but there is no method for setting a write timeout. I have set the connect timeout but this does not help either.